# How to Minimize the Code of JavaScript In DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am Using jQuery date picker,and I have created multiple instances of DatePicker  ([an example](http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/myvaf/))

In JavaScript this script is used four time:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage:"images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true });
```

I want to minimize the code of javascript. What should I do?

Comment: Fiddle is at  http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/myvaf/

Answer (score 3):

You can select all ids together:

```
$( "#datepicker, #datepicker2, #datepicker3, #datepicker4" ).datepicker({
    ...
```

Although, personally I would've introduced class `my-datepicker` and used it:

```
$(".my-datepicker").datepicker({
```

Comment: @prem Add `class="my-datepicker"` to each input (you can also remove id attribute then).  **S.M.09** already shows full example.

Answer (score 2):

You could give each of the `input` elements same class say `myDatepicker` and then try

Here is the HTML

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="myDatepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="myDatepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker3" class="myDatepicker"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker4" class="myDatepicker"></p>
```

and javascript

```
        $( ".myDatepicker" ).datepicker({ showOn: "button",

          buttonImage:"images/calendar.gif",

          buttonImageOnly: true 
         });
```

and here try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sangeet_smenon/LWkYg/)

Comment: can you please give me the fiddle of this..i am not getting your whole point

Comment: @prem: hey I have updated the post have a look at it....and also posted the fiddle

Comment: Now i got what you wanted to say thax  dude